# Why does app crash when downloading over 3g, but not over WiFi?

Tags: android, crash, download

For some reason, every time a user clicks the download button while on 3g data, the screen turns completely black, and the app requests a force close.

```
    private final String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/folder";


    public void DownloadFromUrl(String fileName, String saveTo) {  
            try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://example.com/" + fileName + ".png");
                    File file = new File(fileName + ".png");

                    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    URLConnection urlconnection = url.openConnection();




                    InputStream iS = urlconnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(iS);


                    ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                    int current = 0;
                    while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                            baf.append((byte) current);
                    }


                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(PATH + saveTo);
                    fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
                    fos.close();
                    Toast t= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloaded '" + saveTo + "' to '" + PATH + "'.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    t.show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e);
            }

    }
```

Comment: Does it happen right away or is there a time lag before the force close?

Comment: A bit of a lag time. About 3-5 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your are blocking the UI thread with a long running operation.

Instead, try making the request in a background thread, [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), or something else, so the UI thread doesn't get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent tutorial here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Also, check out [ASYNC from google android api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) as @Robert suggested as an option:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```